Improper integral involving four integration variables
I would like to know for which values of the parameter $a\in\mathbb{N}$ the following integral is diverging:
$$
\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}x_1\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}x_2\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}x_3\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}x_4 \,\frac{1}{(x_1+x_2)^{\frac{a}{2}}}\left(\frac{x_1\,x_2}{x_1+x_2}+x_3+x_4\right)^{\frac{a}{2}-1}\,\exp\left({-{x_1}-{x_2}-x_3-x_4-\frac{1}{\frac{x_1\,x_2}{x_1+x_2}+x_3+x_4}}\right)\,,
$$
I think that there are no problems of divergence at $+\infty$ thanks to the exponentials of $-x_i$ for $i=1,2,3,4$, but at $0$ I'm not sure. Any help?
